# TabLayout error pointing into volley

Tags: android

I have tab layout and it has a weird error. I am using `setUserVisibleHint` to always refresh the tab once it was selected.

I only get the error when I press the tab 3 and the active state is on tab 1. But if the active state is on tab 2 and if I use swipe instead of pressing title, it's working fine.

```
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        list.setAdapter(new CHAdapter(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

The error is pointing into volley request but I think it is configured well.

Here's a sample of my volley request

```
        final RequestQueue req2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        final String api_url2 = "this/is/confidential/api";
        final JSONObject jsonBody2 = new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonBody2.put("username", username);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, api_url2, jsonBody2,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray histories = response.getJSONArray("History");


                            for (int i = 0; i < histories.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject history = histories.getJSONObject(i);

                                String time = history.getString("timerequest");
                                String tb = history.getString("totalcashbackbonus");
                                String st = history.getString("status");

                                list.add(new SingleRow(time, tb, st));
                            }

                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        req2.stop();
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        req2.stop();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String encodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString("blaaaah:pignoi".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);

                return headers;
            }
        };

        req2.add(jsonObjectRequest2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain one boolean variable. Not load page if already loaded.

```
boolean isLoaded = false;

public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && !isLoaded) {
        list.setAdapter(new CHAdapter(getActivity()));
        isLoaded=true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
 CHAdapter chAdapter=new CHAdapter(getActivity());
```

in `onCreateView()` just set adapter.

```
 list.setAdapter(new CHAdapter(getActivity()));
```

Now in

```
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        //Do API Stuff here 
    }
}
```

In your API Success response just

```
chAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I need to reload it everytime the tab is active because the API transaction is changing over the time.

Comment: so don't initialize `CHAdapter()` every time just instantiate outside `setUserVisibleHint()` and then call your api and then just use `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Is it inside the onCreateView?